# Conditionals usage

Tags: regex, pcre

Please elucidate me such issue : How can I apply certain pattern to an input string depending on other pattern match? For example, `lalalala Hedcbw LULU pol GDTE`. So if `pol` occurs at any place of the string then subpattern ,say `la{2},` will be applied to the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this example at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/mF4jO4/2), if that's what you mean:

```
^(?(?=.*\bpol).*?(la{2})|.*?(LU{2}))
```

If the conditon matches - check @ start: Any amount of characters, followed by `\b` word-boundary, follwed by `pol`, the first pattern is used, else the second.

Read [more about conditionals.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)